# Name 'wave' not defined

Tags: python, wav

I have this piece of Python code for audio:

```
import wave
space_oddity = wave.open('space_oddity.wav','rb')
```

that yields the error 'name 'wave' is not defined'

The file wave.py is in the anaconda/lib/python2.7 folder. I work in Documents which is on the same level as anaconda. As for the wave module, I cannot find it, but I don't get an error message when I import wave so that cannot be it.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `pip install wave`, and it will put it in the right location for you automagically

Comment: @heinst: It worked. Thanks heinst.

Comment: good! glad its working